# Java subclass constructor inherited member

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, superclass

I have a question as to why does this piece of code, when executed, prints out the value 0. I don't exactly understand what happens in the SubClass constructor, and why is it that when I erase the overridden method implicitValue, it prints out 10. Does the SubClass constructor make use of the SuperClass constructor? 
Thank you.

```
class SuperClass {
    protected int superClassValue;

    public SuperClass() {
        superClassValue = implicitValue();
    }

    public int implicitValue() {
        return 10;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return superClassValue;
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private int subClassValue;

    public SubClass() {
        subClassValue = 20;

    }

    public int implicitValue() {
        return subClassValue;

    }
}

class Example {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        SubClass ss = new SubClass();
        System.out.println("The value is " + ss.getValue());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR

Problem is that `implicitValue` from `SubClass` is used by superclass implicit SuperClass constructor (`super()`) via `implicitValue()` method, before `subClassValue = 20;` will be executed in SubClass constructor, so it returns default value of `subClassValue` which for `int` field is `0`.

---

> Does the SubClass constructor make use of the SuperClass constructor?

Yes, subclass constructor at start always invokes superclass constructor, so code

```
public SubClass() {
    subClassValue = 20;
}
```

is same as

```
public SubClass() {
    super();//superclass constructor
    subClassValue = 20;
}
```

But lets take a look at your code. You are printing result of `getVlaue()` method which exists in your superclass

```
public int getValue() {
    return superClassValue;
}
```

As you see it returns value of `superClassValue`. Before you invoke `getVlaue()` you are creating `ss` instance, so you are invoking code

```
super();//superclass constructor
subClassValue = 20;
```

which means you are invoking constructor of superclass which looks like

```
public SuperClass() {
    superClassValue = implicitValue();
}
```

so `this.superClassValue` is initialized with returned value of `implicitValue()` method, but because of [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) (late binding) JVM will try to search for implementation of this method starting from actual class of `this` which is `SubClass`, and since this class has its own overridden version it will be invoked

```
public int implicitValue() {
    return subClassValue;
}
```

but `subClassValue` wasn't set to anything yet

```
super();// <-- we are still here
subClassValue = 20;// this line was not executed yet
```

so `subClassValue` still has its default value `0`, which means that

```
superClassValue = implicitValue(); //will be initialized with 0;
```

so

```
public int getValue() {
    return superClassValue;
}
```

will return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your case: SuperClass constructor will be called by default.
2. Logic for new SubClass().

It will call the constructor of the SuperClass first. When the constructor of the SuperClass is being called - A value return from the implicitValue() will be assigned to the variable superClassValue - The method implicitValue() being called is the method Of the SubClass (NOT the implicitValue() of SupperClass as you thought - Polymorphism feature of OOP).

When the implicitValue() of the SubClass is being called, the field subClassValue is not initialized yet so the field subClassValue still be ZERO. That is the reason you see Zero in the output.

3. When you remove override the implicitValue from the SubClass. the implicitValue() being called is the implicitValue() of the SupperClass --> This is why you see 10 in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the subclass constructor implicitly calls the superclass constructor if such a call is not explicitly given.  But it prints `0` because of the fact that the `implicitValue` method is overridden in `SubClass`.

1. The superclass constructor is called.  Here, the `SuperClass` part of the object is created.  All variables are initialized.  Because there is no explicit value given, the compiler gives `superClassValue` the default value, `0`.  The superclass constructor then calls `implicitValue()`, which calls the subclass's method.  This method returns `superClassValue`, which was initialized to `0`.  This value is explicitly assigned back to `superClassValue`.
2. The subclass initializes its `subClassValue` to `10`.
3. The `getValue()` method is called, and it returns `superClassValue`, which is `0`.  `The value is 0` is printed.

If you were to remove the `implicitValue` method in `SubClass`, then it would inherit `SuperClass`'s version of the method, which returns `10`.

If you were to modify the `implicitValue` method in `SubClass` to return `5`, then it would initialize `superClassValue` to `5`, and it would print `The value is 5`.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like something is wrong with your Override method or subclass. Because it sounds like when it is implements a variable the value is not getting instantiated so it is defaulting to 0 and then when you remove it the super class takes over resulting in you getting the value 10.